On endomorphism algebra of minimal left ideals
Let $A$ be a simple $K$-algebra with minimal left ideal $L$. By Schur's lemma $D:=\text{End}_A(L)$ is a centrally simple $K$-division algebra. $D$ acts as a ring of right operators of $L$, endowing $L$ with the structure of bimodule ${}_AL_D$. We can define the dimension of $L$ as a right $D$-vector space by $\dim_D(L)=d$.
By Weddurburn theorem, ${}_AA\cong L^d$ as left modules and $A\cong \text{Mat}_d(D)$ as algebras. Additionally, $1_A=e_1+\cdots+e_d$, where $\{e_i\mid 1\le i \le d\}$ is a set of orthogonal primitive idempotents of $A$. So, $Ae_i \cong L$.
Is $e_iL \cong D$?
Added later
I think I have an indirect proof. However, I would like to prove it without matrices.
Suppose $E_{ij}$ denotes $d \times d$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is 1 and the rest are zero. We can consider $e_i$ to be $E_{ii}$ in $\text{Mat}_d(D)$. Then, $\text{Mat}_d(D)E_{ii}$ is a left ideal of $\text{Mat}_d(D)$, and its elements just matrices whose columns are zero except the ith column. So $\text{Mat}_d(D)E_{ii} \cong D^n$ as a $D$-vector spaces. Clearly, $E_{ii}\text{Mat}_d(D)E_{ii}$ contains matrices whose entries are zero except the $(i,i)$ entry. Consequently, $$E_{ii}\text{Mat}_d(D)E_{ii} \cong D.$$ Coming back to the abstract sense, we can say $$e_iAe_i=e_iW \cong D.$$
